# How to get unique value in array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unique

My Database

```
Tables_sup |
+------------------+
| supid            |                
  scompany        | 
| scategory        | 
| smarket           |
|
```

MY PHP Code

```
<?php
require_once 'DBConnect.php';



    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","gb","123");
        if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
        }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"test_database");



    $sql=mysqli_query($con,'SELECT DISTINCT sup.supid,sup.smarket FROM sup order by supid desc');
    $i=0;
    $dyn_table='<table border="1" cellpadding="10">';
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

     $supid = $row["supid"];
     $smarket = $row["smarket"];

     if ($i%5==0){

        $dyn_table.='<tr><td>'.$smarket. '<td>';

      }else{

        $dyn_table.='<td>'.$smarket. '<td>';

     }
     $i++;
}

$dyn_table.= '<tr><table>' ;   
?>
```

MY HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $dyn_table;?>

</body>
</html>
```

**My Question**
The result is OK, but with a duplicate.How to get the unique result?

Comment: You should check [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: Select distinct return only not duplicated     so ...  update you question with a datasample  ., your actual result and the expected  result

Comment: What is you expected result ??

Comment: The result is coming with the duplicate.I am trying to add image of result, but I unable to attach

Comment: I want only unique result

Comment: Google "Select unique values from database" and your done. Some basic research is allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the id column of your sup table is the primary key and therefore unique anyway, your distinct query makes no sense - every found result has a different id anyway, therefore it can return multiple rows with the same smarket.

Query for distinct smarket (without supid) and you will get your desired resultset

```
SELECT DISTINCT smarket FROM sup
```

I see some mistakes in your tableconstruction as well (closing tr tags for example)

```
// every fifth row is gonna be different?
if ($i%5==0){
   $dyn_table.='<tr class="fifthrow"><td>'.$smarket. '</td></tr>';
}else{
   $dyn_table.='<tr><td>'.$smarket. '</td></tr>';
}
```

and in the end, dont open another tr and table ;) `$dyn_table.= '</table>' ;`

edit: forgot to add some closing tags for table

Answer (score 1):

in your circumstance, you can try `group by` function.